# Why the messages of CMake tests are only shown in the end of execution?

Tags: debugging, concurrency, cmake

I have written a `CMakeFile` that simply creates a test:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)

project (hello_test)

enable_testing ()
set (all_tests "")

list (APPEND all_tests hello_test)
add_executable (hello_test hello_test.c)
add_test (NAME hello_test COMMAND hello_test)
```

The test is as follow :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("This message should appear when the test is launched \n"); //1st message
    sleep(5); //sleep for 5s
    printf ("This message should appear after 5 s \n"); //2nd message
}
```

I run the generated test using `./hello_test.exe`.

What I expected is that the 1st message appear and then the program sleep for 5s and then the 2nd message appears.

However what I see is that the messages are only shown in the end of execution of the program

So if I want to debug a concurrent test(see which instruction is executed before the other using `printf`) it want help me a lot.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of the program as I expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` buffer has not been flushed you could either flush to `stdout` or do `fprintf(stdout, "...");`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("This message should appear when the test is launched \n"); //1st message
    fflush(stdout); // add this
    sleep(5); //sleep for 5s
    printf ("This message should appear after 5 s \n"); //2nd message
}
```

Another thing could be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    fprintf (stdout, "This message should appear when the test is launched \n"); //Notice the fprintf
    sleep(5); //sleep for 5s
    fprintf (stdout, "This message should appear after 5 s \n"); //Notice the fprintf
}
```

Comment: Well, It works, Thanks, could you please explain more "The printf buffer has not been flushed" ?

Comment: @Varum Tewari, I read in forums that stdout stream is buffered and it can be flushed by `fflush` or a `\n` but here the messages are ended by a `\n` so they should be printed could you please explain more "The printf buffer has not been flushed" ?

Comment: What compiler are you using for you program? @Mouin

Comment: it s gcc compiler from Mingw toolchain

Comment: AFAIK in cygwin `stdout` is a pipe and not a terminal hence adding a new line does not flush the buffer. I am not sure about Mingw though

Comment: OK I Will check.